# ContextMenuStrip - Prevent item-selection by key-press

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When a ContextMenuStrip is open with, say, an option for `Copy` - if the user presses `C` - `Copy` is selected.

How can this be prevented?

Comment: First, _why_ do you want to prevent this?  Selecting the matching menu item on a keystroke is standard Windows behavior.  Changing it will make life difficult for users that use the keyboard.  (Not just power users... think about accessibility for users that can't use a mouse, for example.)

Comment: @JaredReisinger I'm capturing the KeyPress event and dealing with the information there. But thanks.

Comment: Okay... but that still leaves the question _why_?  The context menu will handle keystrokes for you... why do you need to capture the KeyPress event yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If setting the `KeyPressEventArgs.Handled` field doesn't do the trick, you may need to catch the `PreviewKeyDown` event and change the event to *not* be an input key (`PreviewKeyDownEventArgs.IsInputKey = false`) to prevent it from ever getting treated as a regular KeyDown/KeyUp/KeyPress.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown(v=vs.110).aspx for further details.

Note: you'll also have to move all your KeyPress-handling code into PreviewKeyDown, because you'll stop getting the KeyPress event when you set IsInputKey to false.